# Symfony installation in shared hosting

Tags: security, shared-hosting

With SSH i install a symfony project in public_html/myname directory. I assign the domain name to point at myname/web directory. is there fault with that way  ? maybe a security issue or something else.

Comment: None of the steps you've listed is likely a security risk directly. That said, the security of your application is probably based mostly on 1) directory access/permissions on your host and 2) the overall design of the application (e.g. how URLs are interpreted, how it responds to errors, other bugs, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Deploying a reasonably complex web app with a security bent is no small task and definitely requires some research. Moreover, there isn't a quick answer anyone will be able to give you since we don't know:

1. How large or complex your Symfony app is(what requirements it'll need from the server hardware, networking requirements, etc.)
2. What hardware you're working with and what your permissions are under your shared hosting plan. Dependency installation, setting environment variables([a common practice for storing your app's config](https://12factor.net/config)), and other common Symfony deployment tasks may require a higher set of user permission.

And this is all without even considering security yet. [This guide](https://medium.com/@runawaycoin/deploying-symfony-4-application-to-shared-hosting-with-just-ftp-access-e65d2c5e0e3d) walks through the process of deploying to a shared hosting platform and makes small efforts to practice the latest security recommendations in regards to config and authentication. You may first wish to peruse Symfony's own generalized [guide to deployment](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html) beforehand to get an idea of the process. Additionally, per your question, consult [Symfony's security guide](http://Installing%20security%20support;%20Create%20your%20User%20Class;%20Authentication%20&%20Firewalls;%20Denying%20access%20to%20your%20app%20(authorization);%20Fetching%20the%20current%20User%20object.), which discusses Symfony's own baked-in security system.

As with any web app, you'll also want to make sure that your app and all its assets are only served over SSL(if your hosting provider supports SSL certificates for its shared hosting).

---

#### Opinion

This is a generalization but usually shared hosting plans aren't suitable for web apps and better suited for static sites, CMS, etc - especially if you're making an effort to be security-conscious. You might consider opting for a good ol' PAAS(like [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-symfony)) since many of them offer more flexibility in hosting web apps.